# Select text inside edittext in Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to select a text inside edittext so that I can check copy and paste option using Espresso. What I have tried is ,

```
onView(withText("text")).perform(longClick());
```

This will perform a long click in Edittext. But text is not selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for simple "catching" part of text you would use [`Hamcrest` matchers](http://www.marcphilipp.de/downloads/posts/2013-01-02-hamcrest-quick-reference/Hamcrest-1.3.pdf) like `containsString()`, `startsWith()`, `endsWith()`.

Although, as you said, you need to match a specific text to `copy` it and `paste` it in another place.

I think it might be pretty impossible to test it with Espresso. You may need to take this action another UI testing tool called `UI Automator`.

[UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/other-components/ui-automator), another great tools made by Google, allows you to test your Android system functions like notifications, screen lock or copy and paste operations. It's working pretty well with `Espresso` test framework.

For finding more info, please read this article:

http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

Hope it help.